# Как на эмулятор закачать картинки/фотографии?

Tags: эмулятор, windows-phone-8

Как на эмулятор Windows Phone 8 закачать картинки/фотографии с компьютера (не из своей программы)?

Comment: позвольте узнать, зачем?

Comment: Для студенческого проекта, у человека нет телефона на WP8, есть эмулятор, приложение работает с фотографиями (просто подгружает списком на страницу). Ему нужно показать преподавателю результат.

Comment: Теоритически, поскольку образы эмулятора WP8 -- это обычные образы Hyper-V, можно попытаться открыть их, найти, где в системе лежат фотографии, и модифицировать образ, добавив туда нужные изображения.
Но практически это м.б. неосуществимо, поэтому остается довольствоваться базовыми изображениями в эмуляторе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Создайте папку **TestImages** в проекте и добавьте туда изображения.
2. Установите значение **Build action** в **Content** на файлы в свойствах `Visual Studio`.
3. Измените **.csproj** (правый клик на проекте, `'Unload Project'` потом правый клик,
   `'edit .csproj'`)
4. Добавьте условие настройки в строки, которые включают файлы в проекте, как этот:

   ```
   <Content Include="TestImages\img1.jpg" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'" />
   ```
5. Добавьте следующий код в `App constructor`:

   ```
   #if DEBUG
       if (Microsoft.Devices.Environment.DeviceType == DeviceType.Emulator)
       {
           EmulatorHelper.AddDebugImages();
       }
   #endif
   ```
6. Добавьте класс `EmulatorHelper`:

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;
   using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

   namespace MyPhotoApp {
       public static class EmulatorHelper {
           const string flagName = "__emulatorTestImagesAdded";

           public static void AddDebugImages() {
               bool alreadyAdded = CheckAlreadyAdded();
               if (!alreadyAdded) {
                   AddImages();
                   SetAddedFlag();
               }
           }

           private static bool CheckAlreadyAdded() {
               IsolatedStorageSettings userSettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

               try {
                   bool alreadyAdded = (bool)userSettings[flagName];
                   return alreadyAdded;
               } catch (KeyNotFoundException) {
                   return false;
               } catch (ArgumentException) {
                   return false;
               }
           }

           private static void SetAddedFlag() {
               IsolatedStorageSettings userSettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
               userSettings.Add(flagName, true);
               userSettings.Save();
           }

           private static void AddImages() {
               string[] fileNames = { "img1", "img2", "img3", "img4", "img5" };
               foreach (var fileName in fileNames) {
                   MediaLibrary myMediaLibrary = new MediaLibrary();
                   Uri myUri = new Uri(String.Format(@"TestImages/{0}.jpg", fileName), UriKind.Relative);

                   System.IO.Stream photoStream = App.GetResourceStream(myUri).Stream;
                   byte[] buffer = new byte[photoStream.Length];
                   photoStream.Read(buffer, 0, Convert.ToInt32(photoStream.Length));
                   myMediaLibrary.SavePicture(String.Format("{0}.jpg", fileName), buffer);
                   photoStream.Close();
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Теперь у Вас есть проект, который автоматически добавляет тестовые изображения в фотогалерею, при условии, что:

- `build Configuration` установлена в `'Debug'`
- приложение запущено в эмуляторе
- изображения еще не были добавлены

Преимущество в том, что это не влияет на `Release XAP` по производительности
или размеру.

[Источник](http://www.softwareisinthedetails.com/2012/11/add-test-images-on-windows-phone-emulator.html)

Comment: @Fike, ну тогда просто проверьте качество перевода

Comment: @ReinRaus - спасибо за перевод.